# CORS Issue with Axios Requests to Ngrok-Hosted Backend API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, http, cors

I am encountering a CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) issue when making Axios requests from my frontend application to a backend API hosted on Ngrok. The error message I am receiving is "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://fe39-156-220-22-73.ngrok-free.app/api/announcements' from origin 'https://9797-156-220-22-73.ngrok-free.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Here is my api.js code:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const baseURL = 'https://fe39-156-220-22-73.ngrok-free.app'; // Replace with your base URL

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://9797-156-220-22-73.ngrok-free.app',
  },
});
```

Here is my function :

```js
 const [announcements, setAnnouncements] = useState()
    const [spin, setSpin] = useState(true)

    const fetchAnnouncements = async () => {

      try{
          const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/announcements`)
          if(data) setSpin(false)
          setAnnouncements(data.json)

      }catch(err){
          console.log(err)
      }
   
  }
```

Although this code works fine idk why :

```js
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  try {
    // Use the axios instance directly from your api.js file
    const { data } = await axios.get('/api/course');
    return {
      props: {
        courses: data,
      },
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    return {
      props: {
        courses: [], // Return an empty array or handle the error accordingly
      },
    };
  }
}
```

when i try GET request with postman it works perfectly fine.

I have checked the backend server, and it is running properly. When I use Postman to make requests to the backend API, everything works fine, and I receive the expected data. However, the CORS issue only occurs when making requests from my frontend application hosted on 'https://9797-156-220-22-73.ngrok-free.app' to the Ngrok-hosted backend API at 'https://fe39-156-220-22-73.ngrok-free.app'.

I have tried adding the necessary CORS headers on my backend using app.use(cors()), and I have also tried setting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header directly in my Axios configuration as shown in the code above, but the issue persists.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this CORS issue and successfully make Axios requests from my frontend to the Ngrok-hosted backend API. Thank you in advance for your help!

[Error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mm92X.png)

also response header content type is text/html and it should be application/json

[response headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzUBt.png)

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a response header; it has no place in a request.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XMLHttpRequest cannot load XXX No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-xxx-no-access-control-allow-origin-header)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is due to the thing that you are making axiosInstance but not using it.
Export axiosInstance from api.js and then call API from that like this :
**api.js**

```
 import axios from 'axios';

const baseURL = 'https://fe39-156-220-22-73.ngrok-free.app'; // Replace with your base URL

export const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://9797-156-220-22-73.ngrok-free.app',
  },
});
```

**Your Function**

```
import axiosInstance from '.././...something'

    const fetchAnnouncements = async () => {

      try{
          const { data } = await axiosInstance.get(`/api/announcements`)
          if(data) setSpin(false)
          setAnnouncements(data.json)

      }catch(err){
          console.log(err)
      }
   
  }
```

Hope this will solve your problem as now header will include CORS